# How to tell WebStorm to look in Docker container for project?

Tags: webstorm

I have my current project directory looking like so:

```sh
.
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile # NestJS Dockerfile.
│   ├── docker # Folder that contains docker-compose.yml file.
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
└── frontend
    ├── Dockerfile # Angular Dockerfile.
    ├── package.json
    └── src
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like so:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  # ########################
  # Back-End Container
  # ########################
  backend: # Node-Express backend that acts as an API.
    container_name: nest_backend
    build:
      context: ../
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /home/node/node_modules
      - "../:/home/node/"
  # ########################
  # Front-End Container
  # ########################
  frontend: # Angular frontend to be served to client.
    container_name: angular_frontend
    build:
      context: ../../frontend/
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 4200 # Angular ng-serve port.
      - 49153 # Websocket port for live reloading.
    ports:
      - "49153:49153"
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - /home/node/node_modules
      - "../../frontend/:/home/node/"
    depends_on:
      - backend
networks:
  default:
```

I want to use Docker and not lose the benefit of using WebStorm as an IDE. It tells me that the tslint package is not installed, for example, and that I need to run `npm install` to install the `node_modules` folder. However, my `node_modules` folders only exist in the containers. Is there a way I can make it so that WebStorm works properly with this?

I know there's something called path mapping, and I've tried to configure it, but nothing happens; it still tells me to install packages.

Here's what I've done so far:

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/04/quick-tour-of-webstorm-and-docker/):

- Went to **Edit Configuration** at the top-right of the window next to the debug buttons.
- Clicked the **+** sign and chose **Node.js**.
- Clicked **...** next to **Node interpreter**.
- Clicked the **+** sign, chose **Add Remote...**.
- Selected **Docker Compose** from the radio buttons, clicked the folder icon next to **Configuration file(s)**, and chose the appropriate service from the dropdown **Service**.
- Clicked **OK** on everything and just ran it. It would run, give an error that the command was not found.

When I run `docker-compose up`, everything runs smoothly. When I tried to add the run configuration `Run > Edit Configurations...` to add (+) a `Docker-compose` run, pointing it to the `docker-compose.yml` file, it works smoothly as well.

What I wish to accomplish is to use the features of the IDE while in Docker. Currently, it does not know where to look for `tslint` configurations, or `node_modules`.

Comment: Did you find any solution @yaharga?

Comment: Not yet. Let me know if you find out a solution. What I ended up doing was write an entrypoint script that installs node modules in the project and then mounted a volume for each folder separately so node_modules doesn't interfere with the volume mounting (issue where it gets empty when mounted).

Comment: Yes I got a solution for what I was searching. It is a bit different from what you are doing, but it should work the same @yaharga

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR;**

Trick is to update the path inside docker container from `/your-path` to `/opt/project`.

**Detail solution**

The issue with webstorm is they don't allow you to define the path from where you can pick `node_modules`. But they have a default path from which they pick it. I was facing the same issue while I wanted to integrate remote debugging for a backend node service running inside docker.

You need to update your docker file. Suppose you were using Dockerfile was something like this

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:12.11-buster

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app

RUN npm install
```

Now this won't be detecting the node_modules for remote debugging or any other integration you need in webstorm.

But if you update the dockerfile to something like this

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:12.11-buster

# set working directory
# This done particularly for enabling debugging in webstorm.
WORKDIR /opt/project

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./.npmrc /opt/project

RUN npm install
```

Then the webstorm is able to detect everything as expected.

Trick is to update the path from `/your-path` to `/opt/project`

And your docker-compose file should look something like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  backend-service:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.local
      context: ./
    command: nodemon app.js
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/project
      - /opt/project/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 6060:6060
```

You can read more about this in [my blog here](https://thetldr.tech/how-to-configure-webstorm-for-docker-container-node_modules/)

Comment: I had other things depending on the current location of my files, so I tried the same solution, but with a symbolic link (it worked). I added this to the Dockerfile: `RUN ln -sf /usr/src/app/ /opt/project`

Comment: None of them work for me :( WebStorm is still not able to find anything, eslitnt, typescript or whatever.
Is there any configuration I miss? I seen docker service it connect find my images but are not able to explore files. Could it be related?
WebStorm 2021.2.3
Build #WS-212.5457.55, built on October 18, 2021

Comment: In WebStorm 2022.3.2, I don’t need to use `/opt/project` in order to let the remote debugger connect to the Node app running in a Docker container, but I cannot use breakpoints (see [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41874)). Was you, @ArghyaSaha, able to use breakpoints? Note that I use `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229` instead of `nodemon`.