# WebStorm node_modules docker angular

Tags: angular, docker, node-modules, webstorm

I use WebStorm to develop an Angular application. I mount Docker for that and it's worked perfectly but in WebStorm I have error like tslib not found because `node_modules` is in docker container not on my PC. I have found a trick to change directory by opt/project and is the same problem.

My source for test: [How to tell WebStorm to look in Docker container for project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625058/how-to-tell-webstorm-to-look-in-docker-container-for-project/65387688#65387688)

Any idea to resolve this?